# SectionList on multiple columns React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I have this data which I want rendered on multiple columns instead of one on top of the other

```
const DATA = [
  {
    squadra: ["Atalanta - Sassuolo"],
    data: [{ id: 1, quota: '1.33'},{id:'X', quota:'5.12'},{id:2, quota: '8.25'}],
  },
];
```

I'd like the IDs to stay on top and the 'quota' to stay below the corresponding ID

the section list code is this:

```
<SectionList
        sections={DATA}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              console.log(item.id)
          }}
          >
            
              <Text>{item.quota}</Text>
            
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        renderSectionHeader={({section: {squadra}}) => (
          <Text style={styles.header}>{squadra}</Text>
        )}
      />
```

[on same column photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QV9i.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<Text>{item.id}</Text>` before displaying quota of each item, as in  following.

```
<SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      style={styles.container}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            console.log(item.id);
          }}>
          <Text>{item.id}</Text>
          <Text>{item.quota}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { squadra } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{squadra}</Text>
      )}
    />
```